# How to set max_length for two fields combined in Pydantic

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pydantic

I know for a single field it can be done through `constr` something like:

```
class Email(BaseModel):
    local_part: EmailPartType[constr(max_length=255)]
    domain_part: EmailPartType[constr(max_length=255)]
```

But how can I set max_length for these two fields **combined**? Eventually, I can override my `__init__` or my custom factory to implement this. But I want to know if there is a neater way in **pydantic** which is a new (and nice) thing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [root validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) to validate multiple fields using a common condition:

```
from pydantic import constr, root_validator, BaseModel


class Email(BaseModel):
    local_part: str
    domain_part: str

    @root_validator
    def local_domain_len(cls, values):
        assert len(values['local_part']) + len(
            values['domain_part']) <= 255, 'Common local and domain length is greater than 255'
        return values
```

Comment: Thanks for the "root_validator" part but using "constr" as you've used makes MyPy complaining

Comment: Yes, there is such an issue, you can find ways to solve it [here](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/156)